# JProfiler keep throwing Connection error, A different version of JProfiler has been detected

Tags: java, intellij-idea, spring-boot, jprofiler

I try to use JProfiler with Intellij IDEA but it keep throwing error dialog with these messages,

> Connection Error
>
> A different version of JProfiler has been detected on the remote side. Please synchronize both installations to the same version.
>
> Please check your PATH environment variable, it might contain a different version of the native library.

And also found this message on IDEA - JProfiler console

> `JProfiler> ERROR: another application or an unsupported`

What I've done are, remove older JDK and try to install the newer, and make sure PATH is point to `JAVA_HOME` and `java -version` command are showing the same version number. And configure settings in JProfiler to use JDK8 in everywhere I can find. And the run profile of IDEA, I use JDK that point to the same as I set in JProfiler. I don't have more idea about why it keep throwing the same and same messages, and cannot search any solutions related from Google.

Here my system specs

- JDK 1.8 u111, 64bit
- IDEA 2016.2.5
- Spring Boot (IDEA integrated runner)
- JProfiler 9.2, 64bit
- Windows 7, 64bit

Answer (score 0):

The inconsistency between the client and server JProfiler versions has caused this problem. Make sure that the JProfiler version selected by Intellij is the same as the JProfiler version being used.